# Asterisks in git log oneline

Tags: git

I am reading http://rypress.com/tutorials/git/rebasing. What causes the asterisks in `git log --oneline` to be displayed?

The sample from the text is as follows:

```
ec1b8cb Merge branch 'crazy'
*42fa173 Add news item for rainbow
3db88e1 Add 1st news item
*7147cc5 Link index.html to rainbow.html
*6aa4b3b Add CSS stylesheet to rainbow.html
b9ae1bc Merge branch 'master' into crazy
ae4e756 Link HTML pages to stylesheet
98cd46d Add CSS stylesheet
*33e25c9 Rename crazy.html to rainbow.html
*677e0e0 Add a rainbow to crazy.html
506bb9b Revert "Add a crazzzy experiment"
*514fbe7 Add a crazzzy experiment
1c310d2 Add navigation links
54650a3 Create blue and orange pages
b650e4b Create index page
```

I do not see asterisks in any of my repos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your link, just above the commit log itself, it mentions that

> "The six commits asterisked below are part of the same train of thought."

I.E. the asterisks aren't a git function, but instead the website pulling out the specific commits they want to discuss through the rebasing tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

May be this is what causes **Asterisks** in git log

-showing your current branch

Also check this documentation

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Viewing-the-Commit-History